# How could duplicate rows be created with the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, schema, duplicates

In Rail, I have this schema (for a join table between car and user habtm)

```
  create_table "cars_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "car_id"
  end

  add_index "cars_users", ["car_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_cars_users_on_car_id_and_user_id"
  add_index "cars_users", ["user_id", "car_id"], :name => "index_cars_users_on_user_id_and_car_id"
```

but due to some bug, I have duplicate rows in this table.

shouldn't the `index` handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
add_index :cars_users, [ :user_id, :car_id ], :unique => true, :name => 'by_user_and_car'
```

it will raise an exception but you can add your own validation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars, :before_add => :validates_car
  def validates_car(car)
    errors.add(:car, "already created" ) if self.cars.include? car
  end
end
```